# Question regarding stably free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

A finitely generated projective module is stably free if $P \oplus R^m \cong R^n$ for some $m,n$.  Show that every stably free $R$-module is free iff every unimodular row over $R$ can be completed to a non-singular matrix.

Now, what I know is that unimodular row is essentially row of some unimodular matrix, which is of determinant 1, which means the unimodular row can be completed to a non-singular matrix weather or not the given condition satisfies. 
So it will be great if anyone can explain it to me, am I reading the definitions of unimodular row wrong or the question is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: See books by say Lang (Algebra), T.Y. Lam (old lecture notes and later text book) or  K-theory by Bass, to cite a few, for definition of unimodular row (explained by Eric Wofsey) and much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of unimodular row is totally wrong.  Rather, a unimodular row is just a row whose entries generate the unit ideal in $R$.  That is, $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in R^n$ is unimodular if there exist $b_1,\dots,b_n\in R$ such that $\sum b_ia_i=1$.

Comment: Ohhh okay okay. Can you send me any websites or books where I can read about this. I can't find about unimodular row in my algebra books that's why.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about it; I just learned the definition long ago in a course that used it to prove the Quillen-Suslin theorem.